# How can I configure imenu to ignore comments?

Tags: syntax, imenu

To configure imenu in my major mode, I need to set `imenu-generic-expression` to have regexps for functions.

However, this is incorrectly detects things inside comments and strings that look like functions.

How do I prevent this? `imenu` isn't confused by the following elisp, but I can't see what `emacs-lisp-mode` is doing differently.

```el
;; imenu detects this.
(defun foo () (foo))

;; imenu correctly ignores this, even though it's at
;; the beginning of the line.
"
(defun bar () (bar))
"

;; imenu correctly ignores this.
;; (defun baz () (baz))

;; imenu correctly detects this, even though it's not
;; at the beginning of the line.
 (defun boz () (boz))
```

Comment: Can you simply anchor your expression at the beginning of the line? That's what the default value appears to do.

Comment: @TreborRude that doesn't help with multiline comments, and in the elisp example it's not confused by the string even though it's not at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting function here is `imenu--generic-function` which by skips comments and string by [inspecting](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/imenu.el?id=59b5723c9b613f14cd60cd3239cfdbc0d2343b18#n816) the value of `syntax-ppss`. So it should have worked out of the box for you. Looking at the code it seems to [jumps](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/imenu.el?id=59b5723c9b613f14cd60cd3239cfdbc0d2343b18#n795) to the start of the before checking for output of `syntax-ppss`, I guess that is screwing up things for you (since it might move out the comment/string by moving to start of line).

I cannot suggest any workarounds since I am not aware of the major-mode you are taking about.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, and I'll investigate further. The major mode I'm looking at is rust-mode.

Comment: @WilfredHughes I am not sure I understand why anchoring the imenu expressions to beginning of line, would break in presence of multiline comments. `syntax-ppss` would return that the point is in a string/comment and `imenu--generic-function` would discard the corresponding match wouldn't it?